# getting character from string that is after specific chars (java)

Tags: java, string

I have a problem getting char from string. **6xˆ3 + 5 + 10xˆ2**, I have this as string and want to get the number after **x^**. How can I do this without using if and for? Is there any method and regex that can help me?

Comment: Yes, regex is a good help here. Do you know regex? If so, please show what you've tried to accomplish this. If not, then now is a great time for you to learn, so start reading a regex tutorial/guide.

Comment: There are two occurrences of `"x^"` in your `String`. Do you want to get the number after the first occurrence, or both?

Comment: Since there is more than one **x^**, you will be needing a loop. Good thing there is a `while` loop, since you don't seem to want a `for` loop.

Comment: I want to find the maximum number after x^ , so I just want to know is there any method that returns char after x^. charAt needs int as input, indexOf returns the index. I searched for a method but didn't find it.

Comment: @Mehran Why "char after"? What if it's `3x^12`? --- And to find the max, you still need to "loop" through the numbers.

Comment: @Andreas the input is a polynomial and I want to find its degree, I know how to use a loop to find the maximum, the only thing I want is to get those chars to compare.

Comment: @Mehran - What do you mean by `maximum number after x^` and did you check if my solution works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String exp = "6x^3 + 5 + 10x^2";
        String[] nums = Pattern.compile("(?<=x\\^)[0-9]+").matcher(exp).results().map(MatchResult::group)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 2]
```

**Note:** [Matcher::results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) is available only since Java 9.

Comment: So close, but: 1) why assume number is **only one digit**? --- 2) OP just [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729083/getting-character-from-string-that-is-after-specific-chars-java/60729137?noredirect=1#comment107446792_60729083) *"I want to find the **maximum number** after x^"*.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks for reviewing my solution. My edit (in which I had already taken care of your 1st feedback) coincided with your comment. I'm not clear about the 2nd feedback. Let me ask OP what he means by the maximum number after x^. Please let me know if you already know what he means.

Comment: Thank you. I got what I want. Please explain a little more about this line `String[] nums = Pattern.compile("(?<=x\\^)[0-9]+").matcher(exp).results().map(MatchResult::group)
                .toArray(String[]::new);` I'm beginner and there is a long way to go.

Comment: @Mehran - You are most welcome. You should first start with [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html). The next thing to learn about is [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and finally, [Java 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html). It may take a week or more to grasp all these concepts but it's worth if your are serious about working in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two numbers that follow xˆ, 3 and 2

This will match on both of those numbers using a positive lookbehind *(If you actually intended to use this character: ˆ)*

### `(?<=xˆ)-?\d+`

If you instead intended on using this character ^, you can use the same expression but escape the caret.

### `(?<=x\^)-?\d+`

Comment: That regex will never match anything.

Comment: I've tested it here and it matches: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html What makes you think it will never match anything?

Comment: Confusing to use a `ˆ` ['MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT' (U+02C6)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02c6/index.htm) character as a *standalone* character in an expression. I'm sure OP meant to use a `^` ['CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT' (U+005E)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005e/index.htm), not a *modifier* character. In which case the regex wouldn't match anything.

Comment: @Andreas I've updated my answer to take into account the possibility that the poster made an error.

Comment: Why are you assuming the *number* following the caret is only one *digit* long? --- Why are you assuming the number following the caret is positive?

Comment: @Andreas Because the poster stated they need to match on that SPECIFIC string. No need to hinder performance if it is unnecessary.

Comment: If OP only ever had that one specific string, OP wouldn't need to find the exponents. They are known to be 3 and 2. The given string is an **example**. `6x^13 + 10x^-2` is another perfectly valid example of an expression.

Comment: @Andreas updated again lol... this assumes it's a whole number, OP can figure out any other details... Perhaps this is a sign the question doesn't provide enough detail...